# Rescaling the forecast from ARIMA model

Tags: python, time-series

**I am a newbie to time series forecasting.** 
 I have a non stationary time series, which I converted to stationary time series by first taking the log and then subtracting from exponential weighted mean. Then I fitted the series to ARIMA model and done forecasting (for 12 months). Now I have to convert the scale back to original scale. In other words, how do I basically rescale the forecasted values ?

I tried rescaling forecast of one month, then again calculated ewma of last 6 months and added this value to the forecast of next month and so on which I dont think is very efficient. Code to convert the series to stationary data:

```
airline_data_log = np.log(airline_data)
expweighted_avg = airline_data_log.ewm(halflife = 0.5).mean()
stationary_data = airline_data_log - expweighted_avg
model_ARIMA = sm.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(stationary_data,order = (2,0,2))
p = result.forecast(steps = 12)
output = p[0]


ewma = expweighted_avg
```

Now I want to rescale the output. I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(0,12):
     forecasted_values.iloc[i][0] = forecasted_values.iloc[i][0] + 
     ewma.iloc[-1][0]
     airline_data_log = airline_data_log + forecasted_values_p.iloc[i]
     ewma = airline_data_log.ewm(halflife = 0.5).mean()
```

which I think is inefficient and probably even wrong. Any efficient way (right way) ?